# Dapper - business object with additional methods

Tags: .net, dapper, data-access-layer

I am planning to use for my upcoming asp.net project Dapper as an ORM tool. The examples I have found illustrate business objects as objects with data fields only. Is this possible to have business object with Dapper with additional methods, for e.g. Person object with data fields Name, DateOfBirth and a method Age, which will calculate current age. Will such object be mapped properly? Simple example please.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can have any other members on your objects; dapper will not care at all. Methods and events will never be looked at; fields and properties are only considered if they are a match for columns coming back from the database.